# Get heatmap annotation dictionary from plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a heatmap:

```py
fig =figsize(8,8)
ax = sbn.heatmap(good,annot=True, fmt='.2f', linewidths=.3, annot_kws={"size": 14},square=True,robust=True,cmap=sbn.light_palette((210, 90, 60), input="husl") )
```

[image]

The seaborn heatmap conveniently set colors of my annotations. I would like to access the `annot_kws` dictionary, but I have no idea how to do so. I essentially want to reused the auto generated colors by `seaborn` in a different plot.

Clearer example:

```py
test = np.array([np.array([0.77,0.21]),np.array([0.21,0.51])])
ax = sbn.heatmap(test,annot=True, fmt='.2f',  annot_kws={"size": 14},cmap=sbn.light_palette((210, 90, 60), input="husl") )
```

gives me [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI1gL.png)

I can change the color of the default annotation to all a single color

```py
test = np.array([np.array([0.77,0.21]),np.array([0.21,0.51])])
ax = sbn.heatmap(test,annot=True, fmt='.2f',  annot_kws={"size": 14, "color":'black'},cmap=sbn.light_palette((210, 90, 60), input="husl") )
```

Which gives me [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6f1T.png)

I would like to pass information to the heatmap, that say lets me change all the white annotations to yellow, but leave the black ones black. And I thought if I can get information on the current annotation colors I could update them based on whether it is black or white with a different color, but have no idea how to actually get that information.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misread your question the first time. I think this edited answer gets at what you were asking.

You can access the annotations (i.e., [`Text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects) through `subplots.get_children()`

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.text import Text

# default colormap example
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(5, 5)))
subplots = sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 14, "color": "black"})

# the first 5 * 5 Text objects in text_objs are the matrix annotations
# the few at the end are default annotations (title text I think) and are not
#   formatted according to to annot_kws; ignore these
text_objs = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, Text), subplots.get_children()))
print(len(text_objs))
# first Text object
print(text_objs[0].get_size())
print(text_objs[0].get_color())
# last Text object
print(text_objs[-1].get_size())
print(text_objs[-1].get_color())
```

**Output:**

```
28
14.0
'black'
12.0
'black' # this is a coincidence
```

Comment: Once I do have these text_objects I want to set them again, say with a different color, but only obj 1 in color 'black' and everything else in a different color

Comment: Take a look at the the documentation for Text I linked in my answer. The get and set methods come in pairs.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I had overlooked this.